# springbatch step configuration ,data from multiple sources

Tags: oracle, mongodb, configuration, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am new to springbatch. I have a situation like this:

I read data from mongo db. `Account` table and columns `acctno, customerno, balance, acctstatus`.

I am reading as chunks and writing it to text file. I don't have a problem with that. I can do using `reader().writer()`.

My problem is, for every chunk of records (30) I need to save `customerno` for all 30 records in a **customerno list**, call a oracle stored procedure with input as **customerno list** and get all details in a cursor output (`custmoreno, customer name, dob`, etc.) and send this output to writer along with account details.

I am having trouble implementing this because if it is a record by record processing, I can do `processor()` in my step configuration and do it,
but because I have to create a list and call stored procedure, I am having trouble.

Can anyone help with job and step configuration?

What kind of step I have to put between `reader()` and `writer()`?

If I use any `taskexecutor()`, what will be my input type and output type?

Any help is appreciated. Coding is done creating a list in reader and calling SP,
but I don't know how to configure step. Kindly advise.

Comment: What do you mean by **and send this output to writer along with account details**...are you simply appending `customer name, dob ` to `acctno, customerno, balance, acctstatus` ? From oracle, you get back data for a bunch of `custmoreno`, so do you identify customer wise data again to append to account numbers?